# Checking the length of multiple lists

Tags: list, haskell, variable-length

```
length' :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
length' [(x:xs)] = map length'[(x:xs)]
```

The code I have currently prints out the length over one inputted list. How do I go around finding the length for multiple lists.

```
E.g. Input:  [[2,3,4], [2]] Output: [3,1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call `length` on each inputted list using `map`.

```
length' :: [[a]] -> [Int]
length' = map length
```

Comment: `map` passes over a list, applying the function it's provided to each element and then returning this new list.

Comment: @AaronONeal: Also note that I am using curried syntax, there is an extra list on the left and right of the equal sign that is implied.